# upnp/dlna servers on windows

Tags: windows-7, dlna, upnp, google-tv

What is the best DLNA server on Windows?  I'm using WMP right now but its not able to play mkv's and I would rather use VLC so I was wondering if thats possible?

Any other suggestions welcome, I'm using the Logitech Revue right now so i want to stream to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mezzmo rocks. Don't have a Revue, but have a Sony Bravia TV, WD TV Live and Samsung LCD TV and it streams to all of them perfectly - including my MKVs.

Comment: yup, this is much better... but DLNA isn't all its cracked up to be right now so I'm getting rid of the Revue and opting for a nettop.

Answer (score 0):

Try Serviio: It is free, and it has never had problems. It works perfectly with my Samsung TV.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Wild Media Server](http://www.wildmediaserver.com/), and it works perfectly. It has loads of options if you're feeling up to the challenge of configuring everything yourself (ie, every little bit is configurable), but it works out of the box just as well.. 
It can also play subtitles, transcode video's for the TV's that don't support the source format etc...